# SQL subquery to compare data

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use a subquery to retrieve penalty numbers and amounts that are higher than an amount associated with a certain penalty number. I have a table that has 2 columns, a paymentno (inidicating that there was a penalty) and an amount. I need to retrieve only information where the amount of the penalty is higher then the amount associated with paymentno 4 ($50). I am unsure how I would test that information and I need to do it with a subquery. Does anyone see where I am going wrong? Thanks!

```
select paymentno, amount
from penalties
where paymentno in (select paymentno
from penalties
where amount >  4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query appears to be confusing the two columns.  As I read the question, you want a comparison using `>`, not `in`:

```
select paymentno, amount
from penalties
where amount > (select amount
                from penalties
                where paymentno = 4
               );
```

If there could be more than one `amount` per `paymentno`, then you need either `ALL` or aggregation (my preferred method):

```
select paymentno, amount
from penalties
where amount > (select max(amount)
                from penalties
                where paymentno = 4
               );
```

Comment: Oh goodness! Thank you so much! I am just learning the language, but that definitely solved the problem! I will accept the answer as soon as stack lets me! Thanks again